# expl3: applying `\int_compare` to an expression

Tags: expl3

`\int_compare` fails with an argument generated from an expression, the expansion of which (3==3==3) is seemingly suitable. Why, and is there a solution?

```
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set:Npn \erw_split:nnn #1 #2 #3
{
    \tl_head:n{#1}
    \use:c{exp_args:#3}  \tl_map_inline:nn 
    {
        \tl_tail:n
        {
            #1
        }
    }{#2##1}    
}


\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\erw_split:nnn
{
    {3}{3}{3}
}{==}{Nf} % prints as '3==3==3' as expected

\\

\exp_last_unbraced:Nf \tl_if_eq:nnTF{{
    \erw_split:nnn
    {
        {3}{3}{3}
    }{==}{Nf}
}{3==3==3}{T}{F}} % F, why?

\\

\int_compare:nTF{3==3==3}{T}{F} % 'T', as expected

\\

%\exp_args:Nf
%\int_compare:nTF
%{
%   \erw_split:nnn
%   {
%       {3}{3}{3}
%   }{==}{Nf}
%}
%% Haven't found an inner/outer exp_args signature that works. 
%% For example, Nf/Nf yields this error:
%% ! Undefined control sequence.
%%<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
%%                           Relation '\tex_global:D ' unknown: use =, <, >, =...

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\tl_set:Nf \l_tmpa_tl {
    \erw_split:nnn
    {
        {3}{3}{3}
    }{==}{Nf}
}

\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl`

Comment: This is what is shows: `> \l_tmpa_tl=3\use:c {exp_args:Nf}\tl_map_inline:nn {\tl_tail:n
{{3}{3}{3}}}{==##1}.
<recently read> }`

Comment: Which does not equal `3==3==3`.

Comment: Note that it isn't testing whether the two token lists will typeset the same thing, but whether the two token lists are identical. At least, that's how I understand it.

Comment: I was hoping `Nx` would make them equal, but it doesn't compile.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ultimately, check that an arbitrary number of tokens contain the same number of items. What I showed is an intermediary step.

Comment: Why not use `\tl_count:N`?

Comment: In your case `\tl_head:n { #1 }` stops the `f` expansion after it so you don't get expansion of what comes after. Apart from that `\tl_map_inline:nn` is not expandable so it wouldn't expand in an `x` expansion either.

Comment: How would `\tl_count:N` solve the problem?  Let me rephrase: I want to make sure a token list is a matrix, e.g. {{{a}{b}{c}}{{k}{l}{m}}{{x}{y}{z}}}; 3==3==3 is true. Counter example: {{{a}{b}{c}}{{k}{l}}{{x}{z}}}; 3==2==2 is false.

Comment: "In your case `\tl_head:n { #1 }` stops the f expansion": [\tl_head:n](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) has a little star next to it (p. 47), indicating it's usable within an x-type argument (p. 4)

Comment: Well, you just want to count them, so you can count them with `\tl_count:N` can't you?

Comment: @cfr show me how you do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what happens with the call

```
\erw_split:nnn{{3}{3}{3}}{==}{Nf}
```

This becomes

```
\tl_head:n{{3}{3}{3}} \exp_args:Nf \tl_map_inline:nn { \tl_tail:n {{3}{3}{3}} } {==##1}
```

and then

```
3\tl_map_inline:nn{{3}{3}}{==##1}
```

which ***prints*** “3==3==3”, but is ***not*** usable in the context of `\int_compare:nTF`, because `\tl_map_inline:nn` is not expandable (it has no star or hollow star in its description).

Defining `\erw_split:nnn` with `\cs_new:Npn` or `\cs_set:Npn` doesn't make it fully expandable, if what's defined with is not fully expandable as well.

Comment: How does `\cs_new` vs `\cs_set` enter the picture?

Comment: @Erwann The difference between `\cs_new` and `\cs_set` are that the former checks for definedness and performs a global definition.

Comment: I take it from your last answer that I surmised wrong that using `\cs_new`rather than `\cs_set` could have had something to do with 'not fully expandable'.

Comment: @Erwann Yes, it's not relevant to that purpose whether you use one or the other.

Comment: You may find a follow up this post in Listing 8 and Listing 15. https://github.com/er-cpp/erw-l3/blob/4d1cafeb42ed5d9c4c8ec940f8790e6deaf0a9eb/erw-l3.pdf